# Transposing a big data

Tags: python, r, matrix, memory-management, transpose

I have a large .tsv file that unfortunately has been pre-processed in a wrong format and needs to be transposed. Unfortunately I am not able to import this data as it's huge. I have tried both R and Python. in R I get the following error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 107 Kb

and in python using panda library I also get a memory error. Can anyone of you suggest you a way to transpose this data without really storing it in memory or a way to import data like as an object and then transposing it?
I have been able to store it as a anndata object but I couldn't transpose it.
Does any one has a suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: the vector size doesn't look like much. Are you posting results on a subset of the orifinal `df`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes it doesn't look so big but even that small amount is preventing me from reading my data. I was trying to read it using both fread() and read.table() in R and in python I tried panda.read.csv but same problem

Comment: Is there a way you can provide a link to the data? If not sample data is a good start to analyze

Comment: Well that's also a problem that due to the big size of data I was not able to open it at all so I really can't copy anything from the first lines! but to give an overview, my data is gene expression data in a tab deliminator format (.tsv) consisting of genes and samples

Comment: can you post some sample input then?

Comment: If not, you want to try out `sframe` / `dask` in `python` which does out of core computation

Comment: Well here is an example of another dataset  https://imgur.com/thif7NW and my data should like like this too but it needs to be transposed

Comment: FYI, that error message is saying it couldn't allocate the _remaining_ 107kb of memory. See page 15 of the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for our hint! I wanted to try sframe but apparently its not available for download :/